# Django exturnal http get request form a raspberry PI and return data

Tags: django, http, raspberry-pi

I wonder if someone could help me , I have started a project using an raspberry PI and django , What I want to do is send data from the PI to django via a GET request and then django to respond with data back to the PI. what I have working at the moment is the PI sends unit_id and room temperature via a http GET to django which works fine but I want django to respond via http with specific data from the database for the unit_id received, for example a setpoint.

Comment: Please show your related code. Currently the question is unanswerable, because people need to guess what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Basically... You need to learn how to develop in django. If you go to the following url you can walk through an entire tutorial on how django works.

```
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/
```

It will give you a good understanding on how django functions and what you need to do to make your system work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply  nut i have looked at these tutorials and what i need is a bit of django help I.E sending a HTTP Get back to the PI and then a bit of help at the PI end taking the django returned data and putting them into a variable.